# Extracting text from xml in java

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, sax

I am trying to create a rss reader for android. So I am connecting to a rss ulr and get some XML information. This is the link - http://www.bulgarianhistory.org/feed/
If you open it to see the source, you will notice that there is one tag **content:encoded**. How can I get the information within this tag? My code just skips it! I am using SAX. 
And this is my Parser class:

```
public class RSSParser extends DefaultHandler {
    private final static String TAG_ITEM = "item";
    private final static String[] xmltags = { "title", "link", "pubDate", "description", "content" };

    private RSSItem currentitem = null;
    private ArrayList<RSSItem> itemarray = null;
    private int currentindex = -1;
    private boolean isParsing = false;
    private StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    public RSSParser(ArrayList<RSSItem> itemarray) {
        super();

        this.itemarray = itemarray;
    }

    @Override
        public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
            super.characters(ch, start, length);

            if(isParsing && -1 != currentindex && null != builder)
            {
                builder.append(ch,start,length);
            }
        }

    @Override
        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
            super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, attributes);

            if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase(TAG_ITEM))
            {
                currentitem = new RSSItem();
                currentindex = -1;
                isParsing = true;

                itemarray.add(currentitem);
            }
            else
            {
                currentindex = itemIndexFromString(localName);

                builder = null;

                if(-1 != currentindex)
                    builder = new StringBuilder();
            }
        }

    @Override
        public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
            super.endElement(uri, localName, qName);

            if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase(TAG_ITEM))
            {
                isParsing = false;
            }
            else if(currentindex != -1)
            {
                if(isParsing)
                {
                    switch(currentindex)
                    {
                        case 0: currentitem.title = builder.toString();                 break;
                        case 1: currentitem.link = builder.toString();                  break;
                        case 2: currentitem.date = builder.toString();                  break;
                        case 3: currentitem.description= builder.toString();            break;
                        case 4: currentitem.content = builder.toString();               break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    private int itemIndexFromString(String tagname){
        int itemindex = -1;

        for(int index= 0; index<xmltags.length; ++index)
        {
            if(tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(xmltags[index]))
            {
                itemindex = index;

                break;
            }
        }

        return itemindex;
    }
}
```

Comment: you need a namespace, i believe

Answer (score 1):

I would really recommend not to use `Sax` on Android, since as far as I remember it's performance is really slow on Android. You should be using [`XmlPullParser`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html) which comes with `Android`, so no need to add any external `jars` and also you will have significant performance improvements. I have just tested and `XmlPullParser` would parse the `<content:encoded>` tag as any other tags, so it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like tag with namespace is ignored by your `if` . Just try printing tag name here

```
 private int itemIndexFromString(String tagname){
        int itemindex = -1;

        for(int index= 0; index<xmltags.length; ++index)
        {
            **PRINT (tagname)**
            if(tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(xmltags[index]))
            {
```

if it prints as `content:encoded`, you would need to modify `xmltags []` to inlcude `content:encoded` instead of `content`

Comment: i tried with both of them and it's the same. i just cant get to this tag :(

Comment: what does tag value? ( you may need to print it first)